# Solutions for differential equations of the form: $f = f' \circ f''\circ \ldots \circ f^{(n)}$

Tags: analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, functional-equations

Which are the n-times differentiable real functions that fit the condition:
$f = f' \circ f'' \circ \ldots \circ f^{(n)}$ ?

I think I have came up with a tentative solution for $n=2$, which may generalize for arbitrary $n$:

Let $f = kx^m$, then $f' = kmx^{m-1}$ and $f'' = km(m-1)x^{m-2}$,
then $$f' \circ f'' = [kmk^{m-1}m^{m-1}(m-1)^{m-1}]x^{(m-1)(m-2)} = f = kx^m.$$
What demands that:
(i) $m = (m-1)(m-2) \Rightarrow m_1 = 2 - \sqrt 2$ or $m_2 = 2 + \sqrt 2$
(ii) with $m = m_1$ or $m = m_2$ fixed, solve for $k$ such that
$[kmk^{m-1}m^{m-1}(m-1)^{m-1}] = k \Rightarrow k^{m}m^{m}(m-1)^{m-1} = k \Rightarrow k^{m-1} = \frac {1}{m^{m}(m-1)^{m-1}}$, since $k \neq 0$ (assuming non-trivial solution), and $m\neq 0, m \neq 1$ (due to (i)) $\Rightarrow k =  \frac {1}{m^{m}(m-1)^{m-1}} ^{\frac {1}{m-1}}$.

With $m$ and $k$ as such we can backsubstitute and done.
Are there any other classes of solutions for this?

**Extra:** Call $f^{*}_n$ the solution of the above problem when the composition goes up to $n$. Does the sequence $\{f^{*}_n\}$ have any interesting property?

Most importantly: is there any associated application or physical interpretation?

Thanks.

Comment: Why are you assuming that the solutions are polynomials?

Comment: No, I'm not. But that´s the first guess that came to my mind.

Comment: The well-known general solution for $n=1$ is $f(x)=ce^x$. -- For larger $n$ this smells like there is a lot of "arbitrary" solutions because $f,f',\ldots$ are possibly evaluated at distinct points. I  suspect one can glue together a solution where all occurring derivatives are increasing ...

Comment: By the way, I doubt there is any physical interpretation/application because the codomain of $f''$ is not really related to the domain of $f'$ usually